# Ignore certain warnings in Idea 11 that are possible in Eclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently joined a development team that had used Eclipse however I prefer Intellij Idea.  The project fails to compile on a couple areas and I receive `XXX is not abstract and does not override abstract method YYY in ZZZ` however this does not happen in Eclipse.  After looking at my colleagues settings, I see there is a "Errors/Warnings" preference pane under the Java compiler and I can set certain options like "Access to non-accessible member of an enclosing type".  Can I get similar options in Idea 11?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's -not- a warning.  That's telling you that it thinks that XXX isn't implementing YYY in ZZZ, which is an outright error.  This isn't a preferences thing - either your code is wrong, or Intellij is failing to parse your code correctly.